# UITableView crashing without error

Tags: ipad, uitableview, crash

This is a fairly simple interface with only the appdelegate and viewcontroller handling things.

I have a UITableView that displays from 1 to 13 image thumbs for a specified patient. I am using a custom cell containing a single UIImageView to display the thumbs. The UIImageView in the cell is loaded in cellForRowAtIndexPath from an NSMutableArray that has been loaded via HTTP request.

The thumbs for each patient on the HTTP server are in a patient folder, grouped in 1 - 3 named series folders. When a patient is selected from a popOver on the iPad, the thumbs table view is loaded with the first series found in the patients folder on the HTTP server.

The user can then select a different series for the patient from a popOver of series names. At which time the thumbs for the selected series are retrieved via HTTP request and loaded into the thumbs table view.

Everything works fine except that I have 1 patient where the first series retrieved after picking the patient from the patient popOver works, but changing series, or reselecting the series already loaded, results in the app crashing. It does not crash in the simulator, only the iPad. When run from xCode I can see that the crash occurs after the last call to cellForRowAtIndexPath finishes without any errors showing in the console. If I step past that point it immediately crashes.

I have implemented the memory warning delegate methods in both the appdelegate and viewController methods. I am not getting any memory warnings.

I am posting my cellForRowAtIndexPath method below, just in case I am missing something when loading the table view.

I am looking for suggestions of what else to suspect besides memory. Is there some way I can get an indication as to what is causing the crash without the console?

Thanks in advance for any help

John

Update: I added my number of rows in section method, which should not be an issue.

I am now convinced that the issue is not necessarily with my code but with the images. Except for this one patient, I can change patients and/or patient image series all day long without any problems. Something about one or more of the images associated with this patient is eating up memory in the iPad. Each patient has 1 or 2 X-rays whose original size is between 1 and 2 megabytes. I am reducing their file size (compression quality) to less than 300kb when saving them to disk files for retrieval by the iPad.  Total being imported in a single series is no more than 1.5mb. At least that is the disk file size total. I have no idea what is actually happening to the file size once the iPad gets them.

Is there any way I can test the imported images for size, or corruption, before I load them to the table view for display?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ImageCell *cell = [thumbsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[ImageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.pImage.image = [thumbsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [thumbsArray count];

}
```

Comment: Check the size of `thumbsArray` and compare with the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.  You might want to post some more of that code here for people to look at.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection should not be an issue as it is returning the thumbsArray count. I am pretty sure that my issue is memory due to the images either being to big or I am not managing them correctly. Is there any way to check image sizes?

Comment: I add my question regarding image testing to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set some break points to debug? From the code you posted, I couldn't see any problem. Did you enable NSZombie?

Comment: break points, yes, NSZombie no. I had forgotten about that. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. I have added a question to my original question regarding image testing on the iPad as I think I am getting something unexpected in this one patient. If you have time perhaps you can help with this new question.

Comment: Images are files, I think you can use NSFileManager to get the size of the image.